# Jquery, $(this).next problem

Tags: jquery

Trying to truncate some code here and running into a problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $('#a1').click(function() {
    $(this).next('#desCopy').appendTo('#description');
    $(this).next('#imgPlace').appendTo('#IMGbox');
    return false;
  });
});
</script>

    <!--Content-->


    <div id="content" style="background:#000; width:989px;">

        <div style="float:left; left:18px; margin:0; width:337px; position:relative; padding:15px 0 0 0; color:#FFF;">


            <div id="description">

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="IMGbox" style="float:left; position:relative; display:block; background:#F00; width:652px; height:258px; background:#0FF; overflow:hidden;">



        </div>

        <div style="float:right; background:#CCC; height:25px; width:652px;">

            <ul>

                <li><a id="a1" href="#">Slide 1</a>
                    <ul style="display:none;">
                        <li><span id="desCopy">Test description, Test description</span></li>
                        <li><img src="images/test.jpg" id="imgPlace"></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a id="a1" href="#">Slide 2</a>
                    <ul style="display:none;">
                        <li><span id="desCopy">2222, 22222</span></li>
                        <li><img src="images/test2.jpg" id="imgPlace"></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: you should explain your problem better, here there are some errors, (same ids multiple time) it's probably related. but we can't guess (or want to guess) what you want to do.
tell us what you are expecting, what you actually get and if any,  errors message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have the same ID multiple times, it's invalid HTML and various things won't behave correctly, including jQuery ID selectors.  You probably want to use a class instead, like this:

```
<span class="desCopy">
<img class="imgPlace">
```

Then you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#a1').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.desCopy').appendTo('#description');
    $(this).parent().find('.imgPlace').appendTo('#IMGbox');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So the outcome I wanted was to simply switch out content back and forth between my ul, and my defined ID divs.

A good point Nick brought up was that I was using same ID which was the main reason.
So I switched my anchor ID's to class's with the following code and got the end result I needed.

```
$(function() {
  $('.a1').click(function() {
    $('#description').find('.desCopy').hide();
    $('#IMGbox').find('.imgPlace').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.desCopy').clone().appendTo('#description');
    $(this).parent().find('.imgPlace').clone().appendTo('#IMGbox');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: If he solved your problem, you should "accept" his answer so that others can quickly see the solution if they come across this page in a search.

Comment: I also added the clone due to only one destination for the appendTo. (So with the clone, it gives the ability to switch back and forth between slides etc). So in all reality we made a slide show with a content description.